# Listen for changes on data in Firebase (AngularFire)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Is it possible to listen for Firebase server updates on the DOM in AngularFire?

I want to be able to fetch any updates when they are returned from the server to update the values of an array. Basically my problem is that I am using `Firebase.ServerValues.TIMESTAMP` which is set by the server.

Furthermore, why can't I use `new Date()` to create a client timestamp?

Comment: Using [$watch(callback, context)](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-watchcallback-context) you can registers an event listener which will be notified any time there is a change to the data in firebase.

Comment: You can bind the Firebase object to you scope.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to use $watch and it solved my problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the `$firebaseArray` and `$firebaseObject` specifically for that purpose. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html

When you call `new Date()` it creates a `Date` object, which is not a JSON type. If you're looking to store the current timestamp, you can get that by `Date.now()`.